# Regex to check for total number of digits with a min and max

Tags: javascript, regex, digits

I want to test a string of all alphanumeric characters and return true only if the total number of digits in the string is between 7 and 11.

> 1234567                   // true
>
> 11qqw3qd1221wqd2132        // true
>
> abc123def456ghi789klm012  // false

The min 7 and max 11 only applies to the digits within the string.

So I know how to test a string of digits for a min and max length:

```
^[\d]{7,11}$
```

But how do i do the same when :

A) the digits dont have to be consecutive and

B) there are other characters or white spaces in the string.

Comment: What issue are you having resolving the question?

Comment: post your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var str = "...";
var digits = str.length - str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '').length;
var ok = digits >=7 && digits <=11;
```

Or this

```
str.match(/^([^0-9]*[0-9]){7,11}[^0-9]*$/)
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to know if it can be done using only a regular expression

Comment: What if you also wanted to exclude all aplha characters? [^A-Za-z]